# Oracle SQL foreign key data not being displayed when selected

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I'm trying to do a project with Oracle SQL and for some reason the foreign keys won't work and I can't see why, there's no errors occurring it just won't display the data when I use SELECT, any help would be greatly appreciated, the code below is the one i'm using

```
CREATE TABLE Customer(
    customerName VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    street VARCHAR(120) NOT NULL,
    customerCity VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (customerName) );

CREATE TABLE Branch(
    branchName VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    branchCity VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    assets INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (branchName) );

CREATE TABLE Deposit(
    accountNumber INT NOT NULL,
    customerName VARCHAR(10),
    branchName VARCHAR(10),
    balance DECIMAL(6,2) DEFAULT'0',
    PRIMARY KEY (accountNumber),
    CONSTRAINT Depositbranch
    FOREIGN KEY (branchName)
    REFERENCES Branch (branchName)
    ON DELETE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT Depositcustomer
    FOREIGN KEY (customerName)
    REFERENCES Customer (customerName)
    ON DELETE CASCADE);

CREATE TABLE Loan(
    loanNumber INT NOT NULL,
    customerName VARCHAR(10),
    branchName VARCHAR(10),
    amount DECIMAL(6,2) DEFAULT'0',
    PRIMARY KEY (loanNumber),
    CONSTRAINT branchNam
    FOREIGN KEY (branchName)
    REFERENCES Branch (branchName)
    ON DELETE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT customerNam
    FOREIGN KEY (customerName)
    REFERENCES Customer (customerName)
    ON DELETE CASCADE);
```

Comment: What is your SELECT statement?

Comment: You need to SELECT from both tables explicitly!

Comment: Please post some sample data and your query

Comment: select statement pls ?

Comment: The query is SELECT customerName FROM deposit

Comment: It would help if you sample INSERTs for tables?

Comment: What's the problem with that query? Are you missing columns are do you expect not null values where you are having null results?

Comment: The query is giving me the columns however it isn't showing any data in them when i select them from the deposit or loan tables

Comment: these are some examples of the insert statement 
INSERT INTO Branch (branchName, assets, branchCity)
VALUES ('Yorkshire', '10000', 'Nottingham');
INSERT INTO Customer(customerName, street, customerCity)
VALUES ('Jones', 'Victoria', 'Nottingham');
INSERT INTO Deposit (accountNumber, balance)
VALUES ('1', '100');
INSERT INTO Loan (loanNumber, amount)
VALUES ('11', '3000');

Comment: You are querying a column where you did not insert anything.

Answer (score 0):

The only statement in which you insert into `deposit`  is the following,

```
INSERT INTO Deposit(accountNumber, balance)     VALUES ('1', '100');
```

where you are only inserting into `accountNumber` and `balance`.
The column `customerName` has no default value, so in this case it will be `null`.
In fact, if you query all the columns of the table, you have:

```
SQL> SELECT * FROM deposit;

ACCOUNTNUMBER CUSTOMERNA BRANCHNAME    BALANCE
------------- ---------- ---------- ----------
            1                              100

SQL>
```

Comment: I shouldn't need to put that data should I? The foreign key commands should bring the data over into the table right

Comment: Your FK allows to check if you insert wrong values, that is values that do not respect the constraint. The FK will not update or insert data for you

Comment: I have tried this and it's worked I don't realise I assumed it would work as access did. Thanks a lot guys